# Apontar dominio para um container Docker com apache

Tags: apache, docker

Fala pessoal, estou começando a utilizar o Docker, mas ainda tenho muitas dúvidas e uma delas trata-se de como apontar um domínio para um container especifico.

Primeiramente eu criei um Container com uma imagem php e apache na versão que eu precisava e fiz o link com dois outros containers

```
docker run -i -t -p 8080:80 --name apache-php --link postgresdb:postgresdb --link mysqldb:mysqldb -v /home/volumes/html:/var/www/html php:5.6-apache /bin/bash
```

Como uso hospedagem Linode, segui esse tutorial para configurar o meu domínio no apache do container e funcionou como esperado até então.

"Name-based Virtual Hosts": https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/hosting-a-website

Porém obviamente é necessário fazer mais alguma configuração, pois se eu acessar meu domínio setando a porta eu consigo ver a página (example.com:8080), mas se eu não colocar a porta, a página não abre (example.com)

Li diversos tutoriais, dúvidas e etc e cheguei a conclusão que eu precisaria configurar um proxy no apache para isso, então cheguei no seguinte arquivo de configuração:

example.com.conf:

```
# domain: example.com
# public: /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/

<VirtualHost *:80>

  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
  ServerName  example.com
  ServerAlias example.com www.example.com

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/public_html
  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/www/html/example.com/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/html/example.com/log/access.log combined

    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyVia On
    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://www.example.com:8080


</VirtualHost>
```

Mas mesmo assim ainda não funciona, dessa forma nem o dominio com a porta funciona.

A questão é, alguém pode me ajudar a finalmente resolver esse problema? rs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui encontrar uma solução

Segue:

1 - Primeiro vamos criar um container e instalar o Apache nele, esse container vai responder na porta 80 do servidor mesmo e vamos dar o nome de APACHE

```
docker run -it -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --name apache ubuntu:16.04 /bin/bash
```

2 - Dentro do container APACHE, vamos executar os seguintes comandos

```
apt-get update && apt-get install apache2 -y && apt-get install nano && a2enmod proxy && a2enmod proxy_http && service apache2 restart
```

3 - Após sair do container APACHE, vamos criar nosso container onde estará alocada nossa aplicação e vamos chamar de PHP-CONTAINER e usar a imagem "php:5.6-apache"

```
docker run -i -t -p 8080:80 php:5.6-apache /bin/bash
```

4 - Dentro do container PHP-CONTAINER, vamos executar os seguintes comandos para instalar o apache, php e o git também

```
apt-get update && apt-get install apache2 php5 git -y 

service apache2 restart
```

5 - Crie um arquivo php dentro do folder html

```
nano /var/www/html/info.php

<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

6 - Saia do PHP-CONTAINER e entre no APACHE e crie o arquivo de configuração do seu domínio (PS: altere todos os example.com para seudominio.com)

```
nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName example.com

ProxyPass / http://example.com:8080/

</VirtualHost>
```

7 - Execute os seguintes comandos dentro do APACHE

```
a2ensite example.com.conf

service apache2 reload
```

8 - Teste seu domínio no navegador agora sem a porta e ele vai abrir

Essa resposta foi baseada no artigo: https://medium.com/@jmarhee/running-multiple-web-applications-on-a-docker-host-with-apache-85f673f02803

Answer (score 3):

Eu utilizo Docker em produção, e passei pelo mesmo problema, achei a solução no container `jwilder/nginx-proxy` que faz o proxy entre os `VIRTUAL_HOST` e os containers , a pagina do github para o projeto [aqui](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy)

Basicamente você inicia o container executando

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

E no container que deseja redirecionar adiciona uma variável de ambiente com o `VIRTUAL_HOST`

```
docker run -e VIRTUAL_HOST=foo.bar.com  ...
```

depois disso toda requisição que vier para `foo.bar.com` será redirecionada para o seu container internamente

não é necessário dar publish na porta do container, as portas funcionam junto com o `VIRTUAL_HOST` normalmente como `foo.bar.com:8080` por exemplo